# issue with making script to delete table with laravel controller

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make script with which I can delete table with single link hitting. for that I have make below code

```
Route::get('delete_table','HomeController@delete_table')->name('delete_table');

public function delete_table(){
    $delete = DB::table('test')->delete();
    if($delete){
        echo 'success';
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

but when I hit this route in my browser I have received `error` from else condition but I don't know why it is not working.

can anybody help me in this?

Comment: @lagbox no that table is empty

Comment: then there are no rows to delete so it returns 0 ... it returns the number of rows affected by the statement

Comment: `DB::table('test')->delete();` does not delete the table itself, as you can see from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#delete-statements) it instead will delete every record within that table and the return value will be how many records it deleted.

Comment: @Remul thank you for your responce but I am making this script to delete multiple tables with single click can you please help me with this?

Comment: @Mohini the query builder does not support dropping tables, you would need to use the [Schema builder](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_drop) instead, something like `\Schema::drop('test');`, but this will always return null, so you would need to check yourself if the table was actually deleted.